# Sell Stock Loop from multiple portfolios

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

So I have 2 data frames in R. One is a table of stocks and quantity that are required to be sold (SSTable) the second is a table where the stock is located within different portfolios (PTable). In addition to the Portfolio, Stock and quantity fields in the PTable there is also a date field. The Ptable needs to be sorted from earliest date to latest date.

I need to construct some type of script to loop through the SSTable and PTable and tell me which stock to sell from each portfolio and how much. I should have 2 output tables at the end of it.

SSTableOP- this table should contain only the leftover shares of what could not be sold .

PTableOP - This table is my execution table indicating which stock to sell from which portfolio and in which order. Would like to have this sorted by Portfolio then ticker name. A note here I cannot sell more than I have in any of the portfolios combined. An example if my SSTable indicates that I need to sell 400 units of AAPL however combined in all my portfolios I only have 200 then it should tell me to sell only the 200 that I have. There should be no record of AAPL in the SSTableOP now. An important note is that I must sell units from portfolios that have the most recent date first. That is the order in which I must sell

I cannot sell more than I have in all of my combined portfolios

Here is some example data as well as the structure of my Data Frame

### Structure SSTable

```
 Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  58 obs. of  2 variables:
$ ticker          : chr  
$ Units           : int
```

### Structure PTable

```
  Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1030 obs. of  4 
  variables:
    $ Portfolio                : Factor w/ 2665 levels ".
    $ ticker                   : Factor w/ 4677 levels .
    $ Units                    : int  
    $ Date                     : POSIXct, format:
```

### SSTable - Data

```
ticker  Units
APPL     400
GOOG     1700
MFC      800
PWF      200
GWG      500
SUN      600
ARIA    200
HEI     100
GEO     300
```

### PTable Data

```
Portfolio   ticker  units   date
HGFR 6/17   APPL    200    20/04/2017
HGFR 6/17   GOOG    800    20/04/2017
HGFR 6/17   MFC     200    20/04/2017
SDSDF14     SUN     600    22/04/2017
DFDS11      GOOG    1700   25/04/2017
DFDS11      ARIA    100    25/04/2017
SDSDF14     ARIA    100    22/04/2017
SDSDF14     GEO     50     22/04/2017
SDSDF14     HEI     50     22/04/2017
HGFR 6/17   GWG     250    20/04/2017
GDSD114     HEI     50     26/04/2017
GDSD114    GEO      150    26/04/2017
GDSD114    PWF      50     26/04/2017
```

### PTableOP

[image: PTableOP]

### SSTableOP

```
ticker  Units
APPL    200
MFC     600
PWF     150
GWG     250
GEO     100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portfolio name HGFR 6/17 is modified slightly to facilitate reading as a table

```
PTable <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text= 
"Portfolio   ticker  units   pdate
HGFR_6/17   APPL    200    20/04/2017
HGFR_6/17   GOOG    800    20/04/2017
HGFR_6/17   MFC     200    20/04/2017
SDSDF14     SUN     600    22/04/2017
DFDS11      GOOG    1700   25/04/2017
DFDS11      ARIA    100    25/04/2017
SDSDF14     ARIA    100    22/04/2017
SDSDF14     GEO     50     22/04/2017
SDSDF14     HEI     50     22/04/2017
HGFR_6/17   GWG     250    20/04/2017
GDSD114     HEI     50     26/04/2017
GDSD114    GEO      150    26/04/2017
GDSD114    PWF      50     26/04/2017
")

SSTable <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text= 
"ticker  Units
APPL     400
GOOG     1700
MFC      800
PWF      200
GWG      500
SUN      600
ARIA    200
HEI     100
GEO     300
")

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# ensure a date type (date renamed to pdate)
PTable$pdate <- dmy(PTable$pdate)

# First determine actual amount that can be sold based on 
# overall portfolio balances. This may not be strictly
# needed but it simplifies later logic. left join in
# case there are sell orders without any mathcing portfolios

SSTableAdjusted <- SSTable %>%
  left_join(PTable %>% group_by(ticker) %>% summarize(per_ticker_portfolio_units = sum(units))) %>%
  mutate(
    per_ticker_sell_units = if_else(Units > per_ticker_portfolio_units, per_ticker_portfolio_units, Units),
    per_ticker_unfulfilled_units = Units - per_ticker_sell_units) %>%
  arrange(ticker)

# process

PTableSummary <- PTable %>%
  # join in the per ticker targets
  left_join(SSTableAdjusted) %>%
  # arrange in date priority
  arrange(pdate, Portfolio) %>% 
  # group by ticker to compare totals by ticker
  group_by(ticker) %>%
  # apply the trading logic
  mutate(
    cum_portfolio_units = cumsum(lag(units, default = 0)),
    gap = per_ticker_sell_units - cum_portfolio_units,
    to_sell = if_else(gap <= 0, 0L, 
                 if_else(gap >= units, units,
                 gap)),
    remaining_to_sell = Units - cumsum(to_sell)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(pdate, Portfolio, ticker) 

# test conditions - all should be TRUE
sum(PTableSummary$to_sell) == sum(SSTableAdjusted$per_ticker_sell_units)
PTableSummary$to_sell <= PTableSummary$units


# make the output table (doenseparately so that PTAbleSummary can be inspected)
PTableOP <- PTableSummary %>%
  select(pdate, Portfolio, ticker, units, to_sell,  remaining_to_sell)  %>%
  arrange(pdate, Portfolio, ticker)

#         pdate Portfolio ticker units to_sell remaining_to_sell
# 1  2017-04-20 HGFR_6/17   APPL   200     200               200
# 2  2017-04-20 HGFR_6/17   GOOG   800     800               900
# 3  2017-04-20 HGFR_6/17    GWG   250     250               250
# 4  2017-04-20 HGFR_6/17    MFC   200     200               600
# 5  2017-04-22   SDSDF14   ARIA   100     100               100
# 6  2017-04-22   SDSDF14    GEO    50      50               250
# 7  2017-04-22   SDSDF14    HEI    50      50                50
# 8  2017-04-22   SDSDF14    SUN   600     600                 0
# 9  2017-04-25    DFDS11   ARIA   100     100                 0
# 10 2017-04-25    DFDS11   GOOG  1700     900                 0
# 11 2017-04-26   GDSD114    GEO   150     150               100
# 12 2017-04-26   GDSD114    HEI    50      50                 0
# 13 2017-04-26   GDSD114    PWF    50      50               150

## determine the unfulfilled

SSTableOP <- SSTableAdjusted %>%
  filter(per_ticker_unfulfilled_units != 0) %>%

  select(ticker, per_ticker_unfulfilled_units)
#   ticker per_ticker_unfulfilled_units
# 1   APPL                          200
# 2    GEO                          100
# 3    GWG                          250
# 4    MFC                          600
# 5    PWF                          150
```

Comment: how would I adjust my mutate if I wanted to change the assumption to sell units from portfolios with the earliest date first? @epi99

Comment: @mannym, i think you need to modify the `arrange(ticker, -portfolio_units)`  to something like `arrange(ticker, date)` BUT you need to make sure that date is of class Date (or similar) to order  correctly. Package `lubridate` is good at this with functions like `mdy`, so adding something like `PTable$date <- mdy(PTable$date)` before the process. If you want most recent date use `desc(date)` (not tested)

Comment: that works as it POSIXCt. Just one more thing can you please tell me what you assumed remaining to sell to be? @epi99

Comment: @mannym, i don't think the simple date change works. I have revised the answer quite a bit, and realigned column names to more closely match. The results now match your sample output.

Comment: everything working perfectly. Thank you so much for your help .